# How to add company name or logo in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to know if it's possible to add company name or company logo in Google charts. I have a chart like the one given below. I want to add logo or the company name to the right of the chart title as given below in the screenshot.
[image]

I am making my chart dowloadable. So i cannot add company name as an overlay. It would be great if i can add a watermark as well.

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
        [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
        [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
        [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="line_top_x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using this code for you chart ?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj yes.

Comment: similar to it.....

Comment: there are no options for either logo or watermark, [overlays](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#positioning-overlaysrelative-to-data) are the provided way, other than modifying the svg manually...